# DataGridView not displaying changes to checkbox when application is launched

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have the following code that will create a checkbox column, insert as first column to the main data grid, and then loop through the rows to set the checkbox to checked. Basically, what I'm trying to do is add checkboxes that are checked by default when the application launches.

The issue is that when the application is started, the checkboxes remain untouched. I've added the ToolTip text below to see whether that takes effect, but no luck there.

I also added an event that will trigger the same code below (calling the same method), and it will refresh the grid with the checkboxes CHECKED.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn importSelectionColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
importSelectionColumn.Name = "dataSelection";
importSelectionColumn.DisplayIndex = 0;
importSelectionColumn.HeaderText = "\u2611";
importSelectionColumn.Width = 35;
importSelectionColumn.Visible = true;
importSelectionColumn.FalseValue = false;
importSelectionColumn.TrueValue = true;
importSelectionColumn.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16f);

// Add column to grid:
mainDataGrid.Columns.Insert(0, importSelectionColumn);

// Set checkbox to true for all rows:
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.mainDataGrid.Rows)
{
    row.Cells["dataSelection"].Value = true;

    // Adding this just to see whether it's set when application starts.
    row.Cells["dataSelection"].ToolTipText = "Testing";
}

mainDataGrid.RefreshEdit();
mainDataGrid.Refresh();
```

Comment: do you have any events that affects your `mainDataGrid` after executing this code?

Comment: Yes, there's a button that will start processes run asynchronously when clicked. And it updates the grid effectively, each row being updated as they complete their processes.

Comment: could you also post that so we can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the code that changes state is not being executed too early. 
It should be executed after Loaded event of the container form, when all controls are loaded and ready for work.

Comment: I was thinking that also, but I've tried to run the same method again after the application is run using `Application.Run(mainForm);` in Program.cs.

Comment: This is it, adding a load event to the form and doing the checks from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check box control to your `mainDataGrid` can be done in `DataBound` event instead of on page load event.

Try to use below code on your page and check:

```cs
protected void mainDataGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow objRow in mainDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        TableCell tcCheckCell = new TableCell();
        CheckBox chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        tcCheckCell.Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);
        objRow.Cells.AddAt(0, tcCheckCell);
    }
}
```